# Uploading with load local data

Tags: mysql, csv, load, mybatis, datagrip

I'm trying to upload a csv file to a local database using MySQL with mybatis. I created a mysql container to act as the server and use datagrip to access the data. I want to use:

```
<insert id="batchInsertCsv" parameterType="string">
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE #{filePath}
        INTO TABLE DATA
        COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
        IGNORE 1 LINES
</insert>
```

to upload the data but my current error is: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides. Using:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;
```

I have set local_infile on the server side and checked it with:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

Can anyone offer help or advice? Thanks.

Comment: Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html#load-data-local-configuration

Comment: I've already checked this document and saw that --local-infile[=1]  has to be used but I'm not sure where to use it. Some web pages say to use it when mySql is running in terminal but I'm using the container and running the mySql in datagrip. Does it need to be incorporated into the configuration file if I'm using mybatis? I need to know how to actually use the information in the document you have provided. Thank you for the offer of help though.

Comment: It should be enabled by adding a connection property to the JDBC URL e.g. `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?allowLoadLocalInfile=true`. Note that there are several properties related to this feature i.e. `allowLoadLocalInfile`, `allowLoadLocalInfileInPath` and `allowUrlInLocalInfile`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html

Comment: @ave Thank you for the answer! Solved the issue and has had fab results. If you put the answer up separately to the comments I'll certainly choose it as the top answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`  must be allowed both in server and client and you have already done the server part.

As MyBatis is built on top of JDBC API, you should add a connection property to the JDBC URL to enable the feature in client. e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/test?allowLoadLocalInfile=true
```

Note that there are several properties related to this feature.

- `allowLoadLocalInfile`
- `allowLoadLocalInfileInPath`
- `allowUrlInLocalInfile`

The first one is a simple TRUE/FALSE switch.
The latter two allow you to set some restriction on the file being uploaded.

Please see the documentation for the details.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html